# State value not updating when passed as route prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am having an issue with version 3 of the react-router where I pass state as a prop on the route as well as a click handler for updating the parent state value.

Although the parent **sidebarOpen** state value changes upon click in the Home component the **sidebarState** value remains at the initial value of *false*.

Is there a way to ensure that the updated state value is passed to the receiving component when the state changes in the router class?

first click:
sidebarOpen:false
sidebarState:false

second click:
sidebarOpen:true
sidebarState:false

third click:
sidebarOpen:false
sidebarState:false

```
var Home = React.createClass({
  handleViewSidebar: function(){  
    this.props.route.clickHandler();
    console.log('sidebarState:' + this.props.route.sidebarState);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
       <div>
         <Header onClick={ this.handleViewSidebar } />
         <SideBar isOpen={ this.props.route.sidebarState } onClick={ this.handleViewSidebar } />
         <Content isOpen={ this.props.route.sidebarState } />
       </div>
    );
  }
});



var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {sidebarOpen: false};
  },
  handleViewSidebar: function(){
    this.setState({sidebarOpen: !this.state.sidebarOpen});
    console.log('sidebarOpen:' + this.state.sidebarOpen);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Router history={ hashHistory }>
        <Route path="/"         
          sidebarState={ this.state.sidebarOpen } 
          clickHandler={ this.handleViewSidebar } 
          component={ Home }>Home</Route>
        <Route path="/about"    
          sidebarState={ this.state.sidebarOpen } 
          clickHandler={ this.handleViewSidebar } 
          component={ About }>About</Route>
        <Route path="/contact"  
          sidebarState={ this.state.sidebarOpen } 
          clickHandler={ this.handleViewSidebar } 
          component={ Contact }>Contact</Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to restructure your component so that you have:

- a root component that handle only the routing
- an App component that will contain the components of the other routes as well as the handle sidebar logic and state
- You other components (Home, About, Contact) will be child routes of App so can inherit the state and handlers via props.

You can then [React.Children.map](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children.map) over `this.props.chidren` property (made available to App by React-Router when you nest routes within other routes) and then use [React.cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to create the children and assign them the state and handler via props.

So your code would look something like this:

```
var Routes = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Router history={ hashHistory }>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={ Home }>Home</Route>
          <Route path="/about" component={ About }>About</Route>
          <Route path="/contact" component={ Contact }>Contact</Route>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {sidebarOpen: false};
  },
  handleViewSidebar: function(){  
    this.setState({sidebarOpen: !this.state.sidebarOpen});
  },
  render: function() {
    const childWithProps = 
      React.Children.map(
        this.props.children, 
          child => {
            return (
              React.cloneElement(child, {
                sidebarOpen : this.state.sidebarOpen,
                handleViewSidebar: this.handleViewSidebar
              }
            )
          }
      )
    return (
       <div>
         {childWithProps}
       </div>
    );
  }
});





ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: @azium: Nice catch.